# How can i delete a helm installed package?

Tags: kubernetes, helm

I'm using Helm 3 to install kubernetes packages. Now I need to remove/clean up what was installed, I tried with unintall but it seems it’s looking for a release (not sure what it does mean) not a package:

```
$ helm install prometheus stable/prometheus-operator --namespace monit
$ helm delete prometheus
Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: prometheus: release: not found
```

When trying to list if there was any release I get nothing!

```
$ helm list
NAME    NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED STATUS  CHART   APP VERSION
```

What's the proper way to delete prometheus resources in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Helm 3 commands without explicit namespace are issued on default namespace: see [Helm 3 FAQ](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/) at chapter **Release Names are now scoped to the Namespace**

If you issued `helm install --namespace monit`, you then have to list your installed package with:

```
helm list -n monit
```

and uninstall it with:

```
helm uninstall prometheus -n monit
```

As you can see, `helm delete` command is substituted by `helm uninstall`, you can see it at chapter **CLI Command Renames** on the [same doc as before.](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/)

Comment: What to do if after uninstalling release still exists in the list?